# Livewire Relation Ship not working with property

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire

Good time, Thank you if they help me with this problem. I actually have this problem in Laravel that I'm new to Livewire.

---

**Controller**

```
class ViewCourse extends Component{

public $course;

public function mount($id , $name = null , $mediaID = null){
    $this->course = course::findOrfail($id);
}

public function render(){
    return view('livewire.view-course')->extends('layouts.app');
}
```

---

**Relationship Models**

```
class course extends Model{

    public function teacher(){
        return $this->hasOne('App\Models\User' , 'id' , 'user_id')->select('name' , 'picture');
    }
}
```

---

**Blade Code**

```
<p>{{$course->teacher->name}}</p>
```

---

**My Error**

```
ErrorException
Trying to get property 'name' of non-object (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\kjjk\resources\views\livewire\view-course.blade.php)
```

Comment: Could you check if it works if you remove the select `->select('name' , 'picture')` from the relationship

Comment: @Remul , Thanks it's Working !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are not selecting the columns that Laravel needs to properly resolve the relationship and fetch the user model.

You can either remove the select or add the `id` column to your select:

Removing the select:

```
public function teacher()
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\Models\User', 'id', 'user_id');
}
```

Add required columns to the select:

```
public function teacher()
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\Models\User', 'id', 'user_id')
        ->select([
            'id',
            'name',
            'picture',
        ]);
}
```

I would personally just remove the select as I don't see any value in only selecting a few columns from the relationship. Additionally it will probably cause more headaches later down the line if you add more columns to the user table.

Answer (score 1):

You have to do

```
$this->course = course::with('teacher')->findOrfail($id);
```

in order to eager load the data of your relationship take a look at doc here:  https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading-by-default

Answer (score 0):

You are always trying to access property from object even when collection is empty, that is why the problem is occurring.

Always check if collection has associated relational data before printing.

If you in `PHP 7.*`

```
{{ $course->teacher->name ?? '' }}
```

Prior to `PHP 7.*`

```
{{ (isset($course->teacher->name) && !empty($course->teacher->name)) ? $course->teacher->name : '' }}
```